# Can I install 2 30 amp twist lock receptacles in a 2 gang box on 1 circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, 240v

I have 10 AWG wire run to a 2 gang box (10-2 wire). It is 1 circuit protected by a double pole 30 amp breaker. Since it is 2-gang, can I use 2 30 amp twist lock receptacles (specifically the Hubbell HBL2620 30A 250V receptacle) in the box both connected to this same circuit?

The 2 machines I would be plugging in would never go above 30 amps, more like 23 amps combined if run at the same time.

Or should I just use 1 30A receptacle and not try for two? I wasn't even sure if these receptacles were designed to be linked together on the same circuit in the same box like normal household 120v outlets were.

Comment: The question I would be asking with a setup like this is whether the appliances and their flexible cords are suitable for direct connection to a 30A circuit without further overcurrent protection.

Comment: Do you want to have 2 -240 volt circuits or 2- 120 volt circuits and what amperage do you want for each receptacle. If you want 2- 240 volt circuits the total amperage of the 2 combined will be 30 amps not 30amps each for a total of 60 amps. If you want 2- 120 volt circuits with 30 amps for each circuit then you will need 10-4/wg. or 2 10-2/wg wires because you need 2 hots and 2 neutrals, plus a ground wire.

Comment: @PeterGreen -- any appliance with a 30A plug fitted is suitable for direct connection to a 30A circuit in NEC-land.  Any further overcurrent protection will be supplementary protection inside the appliance itself. (See  NEC 240.5 for what's going on here.)

Comment: But presumablly before fitting a 30A plug to an appliance you need to check it's suitable.

Comment: The machines I am referring to come with simply a wire and I can fit ANY appropriate plug and use any compatible outlet. They did this for versatility since they do not know what kind of outlets a person might already be using. I talked with someone at the company who told me this. The machine uses 16 amps at 240v and I have another machine I'd like to run on the same circuit that uses 6.5 amps at 240v and I am simply asking if I can install another outlet in this box and use both at the same time, which would never exceed 23 amps.

Answer (score 2):

*This keeps coming up:* The question of whether you can put more than one receptacle on a 30A circuit.

All the receptacles must be 30A.   (NEC 210.2B3)

It's very surprising to find 30A plugs on machines that fall considerably short of 30A. Generally they use a 15A or 20A plug if they are able.

I'm not sure you can fit two of those connectors two abreast in a 2-gang box.  That's a mighty tight fit, and I'm concerned with the screws striking each other.

It'll be tight and awkward to grab, and depending on the plug, they might interfere. I'd go a double-gang bolted to a single-gang with a conduit nipple.

Big receptacles don't have 2 screws, so you'll need to pigtail them.  The extra wire count will mean you'll have a lot of box fill, in both the Code requirements and in the actual sense. You'll need a very deep box.

Comment: The machines I am referring to come with simply a wire and I can fit ANY appropriate plug and use any compatible outlet. They did this for versatility since they do not know what kind of outlets a person might already be using. I talked with someone at the company who told me this. The machine uses 16 amps at 240v and I have another machine I'd like to run on the same circuit that uses 6.5 amps at 240v and I am simply asking if I can install another outlet in this box and use both at the same time, which would never exceed 23 amps. The Hubbell receptacles I am asking about have 2 screws